# touchend event not firing on iphone

Tags: javascript, iphone, onclick

I am trying to have a counter based on an image. the onclick event works fine in desktop browsers and ipad safari but not in iphone. so i am trying to add event listener for 'touchend'. it still doesn't fire in iphone. what is missing? thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Counter</title>
</head>
<body>
    <span class="counter">
    <div>

         <span id="appCounter" style = "font-size:80px">0</span>

         <!--  onclick="changeQty('appCounter', 1); -->
         <img id="plus"
         src='http://www.pixempire.com/images/preview/plus-circular-mini-button-icon.jpg' height='62px' width='62px'></img>
         </div>
         <p>
    </span>

    <script type="text/javascript">

          var elmt = document.getElementById( "plus" );
          elmt.addEventListener('touchend', function(evt) {
            evt.preventDefault();
            changeQty('appCounter', 1);
          }, false);


        function changeQty(elm, val) {
            var obj = document.getElementById(elm);
            obj.innerHTML = Math.min(Math.max(parseInt(obj.innerHTML) + val, 0), 9);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `elmt.ontouchend=function(){};`